# Symfony Doctrine creating complex queries

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a mysql query and it's not really complex but I can't seem to wrap my head on how I should approach writing this in Symfony.

First here is the query:

```
select
   db1.table1.acronym
 , db1.table1.name
 , db2.table1.name
from db1.table1, db2.table1 
where db1.table1.acronym like concat('%', @t1, '%') 
or db1.table1.name like concat('%', @t1,'%') 
or db2.table1.name like concat('%', @t1,'%');
```

I am basically trying to see if t1 is part of any word in those columns. Assume `@t1` is a variable being passed. I am not sure if I should write this in a Repository and if so how. I am looking for the best practice method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you would want to configurate two Doctrine DB connections for first database and second. It would look like this (I assume that you don't have created Entities for the tables yet):

```
//in config.yml

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: db1
        connections:
            db1:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            db2:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

Note here we use parameter database_name2 in 'dbname' for db2 connection, other parameters most likely will be the same, unless you have the other database on another server, so you should create parameters accordingly in parameters.yml.

Then, you can get your connections to separate databases in, for example, controller action, like this:

```
//SomeController.php

$connection1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('db1');
$connection2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('db2');


$results1 = $connection1->fetchAll('SELECT acronym, name FROM table1 ...');
$results2 = $connection2->fetchAll('SELECT name FROM table2 ...')
```

**NOTE**, that this is not best practice. Best practice would be create entities for the tables, and then create separate entity managers along connections that I created above.

[How to properly setup multiple connections with entity managers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: Also not mentioned is to edit parameters.yml to get config.yml variables to work like, dbname:   "%database_name2%"
parameters.yml:
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_user: myusername
    database_password: mypassword
    database_name: db1
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: fsfaffffafaf

    database_host2: 127.0.0.1
    database_port2: null
    database_user2: meusername
    database_password2: password
    database_name2: db2

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't have a join, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if you just want to find all the entities in `db1.table1` and `db2.table1`, these really should be 2 separate queries.

Also with Doctrine, it's hard to use multiple databases, so unless you have a good reason for that, I suggest you moving both tables to the same database and renaming `db2.table1` to `db1.table2`.

After this, the QueryBuilder in `Table1Repository` to find entities in `table1` would like this:

```
public function findByNameOrAcronymLike($nameOrAcronym) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('table1')
            ->where('table1.acronym LIKE :t1')
            ->or('table1.name LIKE :nameOrAcronym')
            ->setParameter('nameOrAcronym', addcslashes($nameOrAcronym, '_%'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
}
```

And the QueryBuilder in `Table2Repository`:

```
public function findByNameLike($name) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('table2')
            ->where('table2.name LIKE :name')
            ->setParameter('name', addcslashes($name, '_%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
}
```

`addcslashes` call is added to escape `%` and `_` - those are considered special characters in `LIKE` specifier

Comment: Yes I have a good reason. The databases are a clients and I do not have the option to combine them.

Comment: @shayster01 In this case everything I wrote still applies, but also read this article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: This helped more:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html